# Why is ((.+)) capturing my content twice?

Tags: regex, sed

I wrote this code, where I capture two blocks of text with `((.+))`:

```
sed -E "s/((.+))[ ]((.+))/\2 \1/" <<< "hello you"
```

So it swaps the two words:

```
you hello
```

However, it does print "hello" twice, despite the reference to the 2nd block with `\2`:

```
hello hello
```

Why is this happening?

---

My original code was a bit more complex:

```
sed -E "s/((.+))[ ]((.+))[ ]((.+))[ ]((.+))/\1 \1 \1 \2 \3 \4/" <<< "if a equals b"
```

Where I wanted it to print:

```
if if if a equals b
```

However, the output is:

```
if if if if a a
```

Why does does "a" become \3 and \4? and why "if" is \1 and \2, while it should only be \1?

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Read the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and [echo(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) and [sed(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html). You might want to use [gawk(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html)

Comment: I have edited to simplify the example, since I think your question is very powerful to learn why double parentheses imply... double capturing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: you went completely overboard with your capture groups.

When you say:

```
sed -E "s/((.+))[ ]((.+))[ ]((.+))[ ]((.+))/\1 \1 \1 \2 \3 \4/" <<< "if a equals b"
```

- The **if** becomes `\1` and `\2`.
- The **a**  becomes `\3` and `\4`.

The rest become `\5` to `\8`, but never get referenced.

You can solve it with this approach:

```
$ echo if a equals b | sed -E "s/(.+)[ ](.+)[ ](.+)[ ](.+)/\1 \1 \1 \2 \3 \4/"
if if if a equals b
```

Comment: why does does a become \3 and \4 ? and why if is \1 and \2 , should if only be \1 ?

Comment: "completely overboard with your capture groups."  You capture every word TWICE. `(())` instead of `()` ...

Comment: P.S.: there was also no need to use **character classes** for the the single spaces.  `echo if a equals b | sed -E "s/(.+) (.+) (.+) (.+)/\1 \1 \1 \2 \3 \4/"` would have sufficed.  Maybe try a [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for regular expressions before trying to use them in anger.

Comment: Thanks for the information I learned about regular expressions not so long ago, still new with it so I always forget things.

Comment: I have edited the question to focus on the main problem and then specify the concrete case, since it seems a good question to me. I also updated your answer so it covers the general approach.

Comment: Cheers @fedorqui'SOstopharming' - appreciate the good work!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use `((.+))` you are capturing two groups: the first goes to the most outer parentheses and the second one to the inner one.
So the content you capture will be the same in both `\1` and `\2`.

Graphically, `((.+))` reads like this:

```
1st group
 ____
/    \
((.+))
 \__/
2nd group
```

And works as:

```
$ sed -E "s/((.+))/\1 \2/" <<< "hello"
hello hello
```

All you need to do is get rid of one pair of parentheses, so just one group will be captured:

```
$ sed -E "s/(.+)/\1 \2/" <<< "hello"
sed: 1: "s/(.+)/\1 \2/": \2 not defined in the RE
```

---

For completeness, your full expression reads as:

```
  1st     3rd      5th      7th
 ____     ____     ____     ____
/    \   /    \   /    \   /    \
((.+))[ ]((.+))[ ]((.+))[ ]((.+))
 \__/     \__/     \__/     \__/
 2nd       4th      6th      8th
```

And you can see how it reads using [this fiddle in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/k3ABBE/1).